# Integer with leading zeros (portable)?

Tags: shell-script, shell

It is a "feature" of the shell that a number with a leading zero is interpreted as an octal number:

```
$ echo "$((00100))"
64
```

But there is no way to disallow this "feature" in many shells, so, it becomes difficult to force the interpretation of a digit sequence as a decimal (or other base) number.

When there is only a number to convert, there are several external programs that could do the trimming:

```
expr "00100" + 0 
echo "00100" | sed 's/^0*//'
echo "00100" | grep -o '[^0].*$'
echo "00100" | awk '{print int($0)}'
echo "00100" | perl -pe '$_=int."\n";'
```

But it takes some time to execute them each and every time they are needed. Acumulate the use of such external tools over many calls and the delay becomes quite big. Just to measure up the delay caused, repeat the calls above a 1000 times and you will get (in sec):

```
expr      1.934
sed       3.450
grep      3.775
awk       5.291
perl      5.064
```

Of course (except expr) most tools could process a file with a 1000 lines in:

```
sed  file 0.004
grep file 0.003
awk  file 0.007
perl file 0.006
```

If all the individual 1000 values are available at the same point in time.
That could not be the case. So, what still remains to be answered is:

Is there a native (to the shell) way to extract an integer that is faster than calling external tools for each individual integer (not a list in a file) ?

Each call accumulates and the delay will become important.

The processing becomes more involved if the number may also have a leading sign and you want to reject invalid numbers.

Comment: At least bash, probably other shells, has a way to force a base — `10#0010`

Comment: @JeffSchaller Try (in bash) `a=-00100;echo $((10#$a))` or `a=-++-00100; echo $((10#$a))` (to get a positive number). or `a=-0010; echo $((33#$a))` to get `-8` instead of the correct `-33` or `a=-001a; echo $((33#$a))` to get this error: `bash: 33#-001a: value too great for base (error token is "001a")` … … ksh has similar problems.

Comment: @JeffSchaller And bash is not sh.

Answer (score 2):

Note that while `$((010))` is required by POSIX to expand to 8, several shells don't do it by default (or only in some contexts) unless in a conformance mode as that's a *feature* you usually do not  want.

With `zsh`, that's controlled by the `octalzeroes` option (off by default except in sh/ksh emulation).

```
$ zsh -c 'echo $((010))'
10
$ zsh -o octalzeroes -c 'echo $((010))'
8
$ (exec -a sh zsh -c 'echo "$((010))"')
8
```

In `mksh`, that's controlled by the `posix` option (off by default):

```
$ mksh -c 'echo "$((010))"'
10
$ mksh -o posix -c 'echo "$((010))"'
8
```

In bash, there's no option to turn it off, but you can use the `$((10#010))` ksh syntax to force interpretation in decimal (also works in ksh and zsh), though in `bash` and `mksh -o posix`, `$((10#-010))` doesn't work (treated as `10#0 - 010` as you can see from the expansion of `$((-10#-010))` yielding `-8`), you need `$((-10#010))` (or `$((- 10#010))` for compatibility with `zsh` which complains about `-10` being an invalid base).

```
$ bash -c 'echo "$((10#010))"'
10
```

With `ksh93`, compare:

```
$ ksh93 -c 'echo "$((010))"'
8
$ ksh93 -c '((a = 010)); echo "$a"'
8
```

with:

```
$ ksh93 -c 'a=010; echo "$((a))"'
10
$ ksh93 -c 'printf "%d\n" 010'
10
$ ksh93 -c 'let a=010; echo "$a"'
10
$ ksh93 -c 'echo "$((010e0))"'
10
$ ksh93 -o letoctal -c 'let a=010; echo "$a"'
8
```

So at least if you're coding for any of those shells specifically, there are ways to work around that "misfeature".

But none of those would help when writing a POSIX portable script, in which case, you'd want to strip the leading zeros as you have shown.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar could be done in one line with:

```
$ a=-00100; a=${a%"${a#[+-]}"}${a#"${a%%[!0+-]*}"}; a=${a:-0}
$ echo "$a"
-100
```

It just takes 0.0482 for 1000 repetitions, 100 times less than using an external program.

That's based on two double parameter expansions:

1. Extract the sign:

   - `${a#[+-]}` remove the first character provided it is a sign.
   - `${a%"${a#[+-]}"}` keeps the first sign provided that it is a sign.
2. Remove all leading signs and/or zeros:

   - `${a%%[!0+-]*}` remove starting at any ( not 0 or + or - ) to the end.
   - `${a#"${a%%[!0+-]*}"}` remove the above, i.e., all leading zeros and signs.

That picks one sign and remove all leading zeros.
However it allows (without error):

1. Several leading signs.
2. Any characters after the leading signs and zeros.
3. An "out of range" (too big) number.

If those tests are needed, keep reading.

---

The number of signs could be tested with:

```
signs=${a%%[!+-]*} 
[ ${#signs} -gt 1 ] && echo "$0: Invalid number $a: Too many signs"
```

The kind of characters allowed could be checked with:

```
num=${a#"${a%%[!0+-]*}"}

any=${num%%[!0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@_]*}
[ "$any" != "$num" ] && echo "$0: Invalid number $a"

hex=${num%%[!0123456789abcdefABCDEF]*}
[ "$hex" != "$num" ] && echo "$0: Invalid hexadecimal number $a"

dec=${num%%[!0123456789]*}
[ "$dec" != "$num" ] && echo "$0: Invalid decimal number $a"
```

And, finally, we can take advantage of the capacity of `printf` of printing a warning for numbers "out of range" (only for bases that printf understand):

```
printf '%d' $sign$dec >/dev/null                            # for a decimal number
printf '%d' "${sign}0x$hex" >/dev/null                      # for hex numbers
```

Yes, all printf use `%d`, it is not a typo.

And, yes, all the above works in most shells that have `printf`.

Comment: 0-9 or [:digit:] are not allowed to match more than 0123456789. This is becaise [:digit:] matches the same as `isdigit()` and that is not allowed to match more. 0-9 is contiguous even on EBCDIC

Comment: I had that misconception as well, but `[[:digit:]]` is required to match on 012345679 only, and not `[0-9]` and in practice, there are systems including GNU ones where `[0-9]` matches other characters in some locales.

Comment: @schily, that's not true of `[0-9]`, there was a recent discussion on the austin-group-l ML which you participated in about it.

Comment: The question is whether there are other collating elements that are in the collating range 0..9. Do you know of such elements?

Comment: @schily, the discussion I was referring to is at https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg02476.html showing my initial misconception, see the follow-ups which address most of the questions you have. Including, yes, that only applies to POSIX for [[:digit:]], and examples of systems including Solaris where 0-9 matches other collation elements and which ones.

Comment: OK, in a UNICODE environment, there could in theory be such characters that have a collating value between 0..9.

Comment: @schily, yes, Unicode is the norm today though, so that's most environments. On GNU systems, only some UTF-8 locales (typically _not_ the British or US English ones) seem to have characters other than 0123456789 (for the system's fnmatch/regex, that's another story for shells like bash or ksh93 that do it by themselves), while in other systems like Solaris or  FreeBSD (IIRC), that's all of them.

Comment: See https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg02531.html and https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg02523.html

Comment: Yes counting [from this chart](http://collation-charts.org/icu442/icu442-ja@collation=unihan.html) (which is the biggest I found at the site) (and if I did the counting correctly) there are 635 characters from 0-9 in that locale. Way out of *only ten*. I'll adapt the answer.

Comment: Corrected case of a =0, corrected character ranges to explicit values,  quoted double expansions (all).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81368/discussion-between-isaac-and-stephane-chazelas).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your example x1000 on my system:

```
$ cat shell.sh
#!/bin/dash
q=1
while [ "$q" -le 1000 ]
do
  z=-00100
  z=${z%"${z#[+-]}"}${z#"${z%%[!0+-]*}"}
  z=${z:-0}
  echo "$z"
  q=$((q + 1))
done
```

Result:

```
$ time ./shell.sh >/dev/null
real    0m0.047s
```

Now I take issue with the sed example. I do see an example with a file, but i am
not seeing a clear reason why using a file is not acceptable. also the example
with pipe is problematic because a pipe is not needed - nor is calling sed 1000
times. if you simply cant use a file for whatever reason - a heredoc would be
fine:

```
cat > sed.sh <<alfa
sed 's/^0*//' <<bravo
$(yes 00100 | head -1000)
bravo
alfa
```

Result:

```
$ time ./sed.sh >/dev/null
real    0m0.047s
```

So on my system it is the exact same speed without the fuss.